# Eigenvector and Eigenvalues of a square matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Define what is meant by saying that v is an eigenvector with associated eigenvalue λ for the square matrix A.

Just a definition question that I was hoping to get help with. It's from a past exam paper and I understand the concept of finding eigenvalues and eigenvectors but I was just hoping to get a good precise definition. Thanks

Comment: A piece of advice for the future: for this kind of inquiries Wikipedia can be quite useful.

Comment: Just realised that, thanks for the advice.

Comment: If you're taking an exam, then presumably you'll have a textbook containing the definition too.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that this is the optimal way of solving your problem. You probably have a textbook, and I'm sure that the textbook has a chapter called "eigenvalues and eigenvectors", and that chapter contains the definitions. Looking it up in the textbook is, if you ask me, the quickest way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $x$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if $x\neq 0$ and there exists $\lambda$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$. $\lambda$ is then called an eigenvalue of $A$ associated to the eigenvector $x$.

Note in particular that every vector $x\neq 0$ in the kernel of $A$ is an eigenvector of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $0$. More generally $\ker(A-\lambda I)$ is the space of all eigenvectors of $A$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda$. This is true as long as this subspace is not $\{0\}$ in which case $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $A$.

By the way the wikipedia article about [eigenvalue and eigenvectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors) is (IMO) very well done.

Comment: @John you're welcome :).